# dense set in [0,1]

Tags: calculus

I need help to prove that: 
$A=\left\{ q\sqrt{3} | q∈(0,\infty)\bigcap Q\right\}$
A is dense set in [0,1].

I understood that: for each $a∈A$ then $a=\frac{p}{w}\sqrt{3}$ when p,w>0.

But how should I choose the p,w that it will hold for each $x,y∈[0,1]$ then $x<a<y$

Comment: Since this is the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498238/a-left-q-sqrt3-q%e2%88%880-infty-bigcap-q-right-a-is-dense-set-in-0-1) that you deleted minutes ago, why don't you just undelete it?

Comment: Do not delete and re-post questions. That is frowned upon, and doing so may cause an account to be suspended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a,b \in [0,1/\sqrt{3}]$ be of the form $a=\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $b=\frac{y}{\sqrt{3}}$, where $x,y \in [0,1]$. Because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ (and hence in $[0,1/\sqrt{3}]$), we have that there exists $q \in \mathbb{Q^+}$ such that $$a<q<b \iff \frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}<q<\frac{y}{\sqrt{3}} \iff x<q\sqrt{3}<y.$$ Since $q\sqrt{3} \in A$, we have shown that $A$ is dense in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in[0,1]$. Then take $\Bbb Q_+\ni q_n\to\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}$. Obviously $q_n\sqrt{3}\to x$.